# How to insert document to specific collection in mongodb using spring data?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

By default save() is used to add a document into the collection (defined in Model class).
How to insert a document or Query to insert a document into the specific collection using Spring Data?
Something like save(document,CollectionName).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MongoOperations` and `MongoTemplate` classes have an option in the `save` method to pass the collection name.

The class `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository` is present in the core library which is not specific to Mongo. So, it doesn't have an option to pass the Mongo collection name.

[MongoOperations save with collection name](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#save-T-java.lang.String-)

[MongoTemplate save with collection name](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#save-T-java.lang.String-)